# R - Memory allocation besides objects in ls()

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I have loaded a fairly large set of data using data.table. I then want to add around 30 columns using instructions of the form:

```
DT[, x5:=cumsum(y1), by=list(x1, x2)]
DT[, x6:=cummean(y2), by=x1]
```

At some point I start to get "warnings" like this:

```
1: In structure(.Call(C_objectSize, x), class = "object_size") :
Reached total allocation of 8072Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I check the tracemem(DT) every now and then to assure that no copies are made. The only output I ever get is:

```
"<0000000005E8E700>"
```

Also I check ls() to see which objects are in use and object.size() to see how much of my RAM is allocated by the object. The only output of ls() is my data.table and the object size after the first error is 5303.1 Mb.
I am on a Windows 64-bit machine running R in 64-bit and have 8 GB RAM. Of these 8 GB RAM only 80% are in use when I get the warning. Of these R is using 5214.0 Mb (strange since the table is bigger than this).

My question is, if the only RAM R is using is 5303.1 Mb and I still have around 2 Gb of free memory why do I get the error that R has reached the limit of 8 Gb and is there anything I can do against it? If not, what are other options? I know I could use Bigmemory but then I would have to rewrite my whole code and would loose the sweet by-reference modifications which data.table offers.

Comment: What happens when you preallocate your columns beforehand? I.e. first run `alloc.col(DT, your.final.num.of.columns)`, and then add the various columns.

Comment: My final number of columns is 97. When I try to alloc.col(DT, 97) R tells me that I cannot reduce the number of allocated columns, since 100 columns are already allocated. However, I just increased the allocated columns to 150 and will have a look what it does, thanks!

Comment: buy more RAM.  http://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I would love to but I have a Lenovo 11s with only one RAM slot up to 8 Gb. I also cannot buy a new computer due to financial restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the operations require RAM beyond what the object itself takes up. You could verify that windows is using a page file. If it is you could try increasing its size. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size

If that fails you could try to run a live environment of Lubuntu linux to see if its memory overhead is small enough to allow the operation.  http://lubuntu.net/

Ultimately, I suspect you're going to have to use bigmemory or similar.